# SSH: auth fail in datagrip

Tags: intellij-idea, jdbc, datagrip

I'm having a problem to connect to my database, it all work yesterday and suddenly today this error show up:
[image]

Comment: Where's the SQL?

Comment: the problem is in the link

Comment: Try retype your passphrase and hit 'Test Connection'

Comment: Check idea.log (Help | Show Log In Finder). What's the full error there? Have server setup changed?

Comment: Please, tell us the version